# Comparing ROC-curves

Tags: r, logistic, roc, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I would like to find if there is a significant difference between two ROC-curves. I've found the roc.test in the pROC package. However, I cannot seem to find any information on how this test is actually performed. Can anyone explain it to me or refer to a webpage that has information on this?

From the [documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/pROC/docs/roc.test) for `roc.test()`, I've found that the used test is DeLong's test (based on the article 'Comparing the areas under two or more correlated receiver operating characteristic curves: a nonparametric approach'). However, I don't quite understand the article.

My ROC-curves have been found by comparing two logistic regressions, where one has a subset of attributes of the other seeing as I want to examine whether these attributes are useful. The probabilities are found using 5-fold cross-validation.

Comment: You can see in the documentation under **References** that the original paper is DeLong et al. (1988) "Comparing the areas under two or more correlated receiver operating characteristic curves: a nonparametric approach". Biometrics 44, pp. 837-45. I don't remember all the details, but the gist of it is that you can use a version of the Mann-Whitney U-test to compare the AUCs.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know Mann-Whitney U-test. Is it safe to use DeLong's test for my purpose? It seems good that it is non-parametric.

Comment: The description of the package can be found [here](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/12/77): "pROC: an open-source package for R and S+ to analyze and compare ROC curves" Xavier Robin, Natacha Turck, Alexandre Hainard, Natalia Tiberti, Frédérique Lisacek, Jean-Charles Sanchez and Markus Müller, BMC Bioinformatics 2011, 12:77, doi:10.1186/1471-2105-12-77

Comment: How would cross validation help with "finding" the probabilities?  Cross-validation is used to study the performance of a model, not to fit the model.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I think what he meant is that he performed a 5-fold CV to generate scores for every sample which he then used to construct the ROC curve.

Comment: Then the original post needs to be edited.  And I'm still struggling with the issue of why ROC curves have any relevance here.  See [this](http://fharrell.com/post/addvalue).

Comment: @bi_scholar exactly. I'm using ROC curves to evaluate the model. To generate ROC curves, you need a prediction (here interpreted as a probability) for each sample.

Comment: @FrankHarrell ROC curves and the associated AUC values are often used to compare statistical models, perhaps particularly within machine learning and DSP. I wrote this question back then because I was trying to understand how I can identify whether two ROC curves are different in a statistically significant way.

Comment: I know they are commonly used but this was never a good idea and is a misunderstand of what ROC curves were originally intended to do.  Above all, the method is statistically inefficient and will result in a better model often being declared no better than the other model.  See [here](http://www.fharrell.com/post/mlconfusion) for more information.